# find_elements - Selenium (Python) : How to fill with nulls (or with other values) instead of blank

Tags: python, list, selenium, null

Good morning,

I am trying to do a web scraping project. I am expecting a list of 600 values after running the project but I get a list with 450 values.

I am aware that FindElements will create a list with the found values but I am wondering if there is any way I can get a list with 600 values.

I thought I could fill the not-found values with na, but I can't find the proper way. If I am not wrong, I should append a nan when i.text is empty. Here is my code:

```
def Prices():
    global prices
    global prices2
    prices=[]
    try:  
        for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eur'):
            if i.text != "":
                prices.append(i.text)
            else:
                prices.append(np.nan)
        print(prices)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print (e)
        return prices
```

Then I thought. If I can't append a nan, maybe I can append another element. So I found another element to scrape, and used the following code:

```
    def Prices_function():
        prices=[]
        try:  
            for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eur'):
                if i.text != "":   
                    prices.append(i.text)
                else:
                    for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eur_m'):
                        prices.append(i.text)        

      print(prices)
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print (e)
            return prices
```

But this code did not work either. I wonder why none of these codes work?

Could anyone help me understand them?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You want to insert `None` in case `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eur_m')` is an empty list?

Comment: If you're using selenium `find_elements`, it will return all the found result. So the element which is empty will return empty string (`""`) instead of returning `None`.

Comment: @Guy  Probably better now :) I'd like to append a nan value when the results are not found

Comment: @MinhDao  Thank you :) This is exactly what I said in the description. I am aware of that, but I would like to know if I can do anything to see what values Selenium did not find.

Comment: @Marta No actually. Please format it to proper Python format. This code is also not entirely Python (`i.text.size()` will not compile). And it's still not clear when you want to insert the `None` values. When `i.text` is empty? when `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` is empty?

Comment: @Guy Thank you for your help. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: @Marta How many results in `find_elements_by_class_name`? 450 or 600? extract the results to a variable and check. You can also try `if i.text.strip()` in the condition.

Comment: @Guy  As I mentioned in the description, I expected a list of 600 values but got a list with 450 values, meaning 150 values could not be found (but I don't know which ones). I will try this, thank you

Comment: @Marta That's fine, but I asked how many elements `find_elements_by_class_name` returns. Not how many you expect, how many it actually returns.

Comment: It returns a list with 450 elements

Comment: @Marta if you have only 450 elements than you need to find another locator that can get all the 600 elements. The if else won't help here, you need to change `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eur')`.

Comment: so you have list of 600 with you , and you are getting 450 from web scrapping,...??

Comment: @Guy  There is no element that allows me to get the 600 elements. There are 600 elements on the website, but (approximately) 400 of them can be located with find_elements_by_class_name('eur') and the rest (200) can be located with find_elements_by_class_name('eur_m'). Is there any way I can get both ??

Answer (score 0):

To locate all the 600 elements you can use `css_selector` that locate elements with class `eur` or with class `eur_m`

```
 elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.eur, .eur_m')
```

You can also locate elements that start with class `eur`, but it might find more elements, depends on the html

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^="eur"]')
```

And to get the text

```
prices = [el.text for el in elements]
```

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.eur, .eur_m') is exactly what I was looking for. It worked :) Although could you explain why do you use css_selector even though .eur and .eur_m are class_names?

Comment: @Marta `by_class_name` can locate only by a single class, to locate by more than one class, or to use additional arguments (like or `,` in that case) tou need to use `css_selector` or `xpath`.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much!